# How can I completely discard decimals after a set number of significant figures?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, number-representation

I have a number with a long decimal tail, like

```
x=1.23456789789456123
```

and I would like to (i) keep the first $n$ significant figures, and (ii) completely discard the rest. I must confess, however, that I'm struggling to do the latter; I roughly understand why Mathematica is reticent to do this but I still want it to happen.

To be a bit more specific, I have a number which I get from a randomized getter,

```
x = RandomReal[{0, Pi}]
```

and I really, really don't care about what comes after the ~fourth significant figure. Moreover, this number will (can) eventually make its way to the user via an error message such as

```
sample::message = "Sample message with an input number, x=`1`.";
```

and in this case it comes out with the entirety of its tail: calling `Message[sample::message, x]` returns

```
sample::message: Sample message with an input number, x=0.7265630732332595`.
```

with a big ugly decimal tail I really don't care about.

Usually, to deal with this, you either

- use the second argument of [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html), which doesn't really do much as `x` is already in numerical form with a trailing `` ` ``, or
- run it through [`SetPrecision[#, 4]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) (say), which appends a `` `4 `` at the end of the decimal expression, which then goes on to affect how `x` gets displayed and how it interacts with other numbers, but which only makes its `FullForm` and its message form longer. Alternatively, you could also
- run it through `Round`, but the second argument is an absolute number instead of a number of significant figures.

So: is there a simple, clean-cut, in-built way to disregard all the decimals after a certain point? I understand why `SetPrecision` does what it does (adding information instead of deleting it, and then enforcing the correct behaviour on that number) but here I'm perfectly happy with 'changing' `x`, much the same way that `Round` does.

Comment: I don't quite understand your objection to using `Round[]`: `Round[1.23456789789456123, 1.*^-4]` looks clean to me. You could write a wrapper that takes significant figures instead.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a guarantee that `x` is between 1 and 10, and I would like to cut off at significant figures instead of at a specific decimal. If `Round[#, 10^(Log10[#]-4)]&` really is the best and only way then that's fair enough, but it really weirds me out that there's no way to tell `N` or its closer cousins to do this.

Comment: Ah, `MantissaExponent[]` might help you with that; this can then be combined with `Round[]` as seen fit.

Comment: Hmmm. Even that turns out surprisingly tricky, both using `MantissaExponent` and the (actually non-functional) `Round` hack from my comment above. The problem is that using `Round[#, 0.0001]&` has a tendency to return e.g. ``FullForm[Round[0.1234567, 0.00001]]==0.12346000000000001` ``. You end up needing things like `Apply[N[Round[#1, 10^-4] 10^#2] &]@*MantissaExponent`, which is definitely enough of a mouthful that it feels like surely there's a cleaner in-built way to do it.

Comment: If you are just dealing with a display issue use [NumberForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html): `Off[NumberForm::sigz]; NumberForm[#, 4] & /@ (x 10^Range[0, 6])`

Comment: @BobHanlon That works surprisingly well (i.e. `x = NumberForm[RandomReal[{0, Pi}], 4]; Message[sample::message, x]` shows the correct number of digits), but then the number in the error message no longer coincides with what's used in the computation and that's not quite what I'm shooting for.

Comment: (Also, in addition, that changes the Head of `x`, and of things like `Sin[x]`, from `Real` to `NumberForm`, which is definitely not desired behaviour. Even worse, `NumberQ[x]` evaluates to `False`, and that's pretty much a deal killer.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, have you looked at `RealDigits`? It lists the digits (with zeros appended) but also the number of digits before decimal (negative if fractional), and the zeros can be truncated: `Replace[RealDigits[x], {{y__, z___ /; z == 0}, b_} :> {{y}, b}]`. Not a complete solution but possible alternative to the current answers?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a built in method but the method below uses only a few lines of code to achieve this.

```
toPrecision[x_?NumericQ, sigFigs_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{y, sign, magnitudeShift},
  sign = Sign@x;
  y = x sign;
  magnitudeShift = sigFigs - Ceiling@Log10@y;
  sign Round[y 10^magnitudeShift, 1] 10^-magnitudeShift
  ]
```

This shifts the number so that the integer part contains the number of significant figures requested.  Then rounds the shifted number to remove the decimal. Finally, it shifts the number back to its original magnitude. Of course the `Sign` bit is needed because of `Log10`.

Depending on what you pass in a rational can be returned. It is of the requested significant figures in decimal form.  In these cases you can use `N` if you like.

```
toPrecision[Log[5], 2] // N
(* 1.6 *)

toPrecision[-1248768.9868, 4]
(* -1249000 *)

toPrecision[0.9384794839, 4] // N
(* 0.9385 *)
```

And so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That turns something with a `Real` head into something with a `Rational` head, which is not ideal, so that final `N` should go in the function itself. The code is pretty verbose but some reasonable golfing puts it at `N[Round[10^(#2 - Ceiling[Log10[Abs[#1]]]) #1, 1] 10^(-#2 + 
    Ceiling[Log10[ Abs[#1]]])] &`, which I guess is close enough in absence of a built-in solution - but surely there's a cleaner way!

Comment: Try this one for size: ``toPrecision[x_?NumericQ, sigFigs_Integer?Positive] := Module[{prec = Internal`PrecAccur[x]}, N[#1 10^#2 & @@ MapAt[Round[#, 10^-sigFigs] &, MantissaExponent[x], 1], prec]]``

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I find it is better to have an extra line or two of code to assist with the reader's comprehension of the algorithm than to go super sleek because I can.  My aim is communication, not elegance.